# Eliminar directorio en Laravel

Tags: laravel-10, php81

Buenas tardes compañeros.

Estoy desarrollando un aplicativo en Laravel 10. En dicha aplicación el usuario puede descarga de forma masiva una serie de documentos en formato .ZIP. Para esta labor he utilizado la librería de Php **zipArchive**. En dicha función genero un directorio dentro del Storage de Laravel que utilizo posteriormente como ubicación para generar el archivo .zip que descargará el usuario.

Todo funciona de forma correcta, pero necesito que al finalizar la operación dicho directorio se borre para no almacenar de forma innecesaria archivos. Utilizo la función Storage::deleteDirectory pero no consigo que el directorio se elimine.

¿Alguien me puede indicar si estoy haciendo algo de forma incorrecta o como puedo borrar el directorio?

Os dejo el código de la función que genera el directorio, recorre los archivos a zipear y genera el archivo zip para descargar.

```
    public function downloadZip($id) {
    $complaint = Complaint::findOrfail($id);

    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    $zipname = "Docs_" . $complaint->codref . ".zip";
    $filepath = storage_path('app/Complaint_' . $id);
    
    Storage::makeDirectory('temp', 0777, true);

    if ($zip->open(storage_path('app/temp/' . $zipname), ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE))
    {
        $folder = realpath($filepath);
        
        $files = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator(
            new \RecursiveDirectoryIterator($folder), \RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY
        );

        foreach ($files as $name => $file)
            {
            if (!$file->isDir())
                {
                    $filePath = $file->getRealPath();
                    $relativePath = substr($filePath, strlen($folder)+1);

                    $zip->addFile($filePath, $relativePath);
                }
            }

            $zip->close();
    }

    return response()->download(storage_path('app/temp/' . $zipname));

    Storage::deleteDirectory(storage_path('app/temp'));
}
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Tienes el borrado después del return por eso no te funciona, debe poner esa línea antes. Eso te solucionará el problema.

Comment: Hola Darwin, gracias por tu comentario. Mi duda es que si pongo el borrado antes del return no podré luego realizar la descarga, no?.